# gawk - Delimit lines with custom character and no similar ending character

Tags: awk

Let's say I have a file like so:

**test.txt**

```
one
two
three
```

I'd like to get the following output: `one|two|three`

And am currently using this command: `gawk -v ORS='|' '{ print $0 }' test.txt`

Which gives: `one|two|three|`

How can I print it so that the last `|` isn't there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert one column to one row with field separator:

```
awk '{$1=$1} 1' FS='\n' OFS='|' RS='' file
```

Or in another notation:

```
awk -v FS='\n' -v OFS='|' -v RS='' '{$1=$1} 1' file
```

Output:

```
one|two|three
```

---

See: [8 Powerful Awk Built-in Variables – FS, OFS, RS, ORS, NR, NF, FILENAME, FNR](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/01/8-powerful-awk-built-in-variables-fs-ofs-rs-ors-nr-nf-filename-fnr/)

Comment: Empty RS is paragraph mode, so leading/trailing newlines and more than one consecutive empty lines will disappear.. and output won't be necessarily single line if there are more than one paragraphs... but that may be what OP wanted..

Answer (score 3):

Here's one way to do it:

```sh
$ seq 1 | awk -v ORS= 'NR>1{print "|"} 1; END{print "\n"}'
1
$ seq 3 | awk -v ORS= 'NR>1{print "|"} 1; END{print "\n"}'
1|2|3
```

With `paste`:

```sh
$ seq 1 | paste -sd'|'
1
$ seq 3 | paste -sd'|'
1|2|3
```

Comment: `paste` is by far the best tool for this job.

Answer (score 1):

`awk` solutions work great. Here is `tr + sed` solution:

```sh
tr '\n' '|' < file | sed 's/\|$//'

1|2|3
```

Answer (score 0):

just flatten it :

```
gawk/mawk 'BEGIN { FS = ORS; RS = "^[\n]*$"; OFS = "|" 
                
             } NF && ( $NF ? NF=NF : —-NF )'
```

ascii `|` = octal `\174` = hex  `0x7C`. The reason for `—-NF` is that more often than not, the input includes a trailing new line, which makes field count 1 too many and result in

```
1|2|3|
```

Both `NF=NF` and `--NF` are similar concepts to $1=$1. Empty inputs, regardless of whether trailing new lines exist or not, would result in nothing printed.

At the `OFS` spot, you can delimit it with any string combo you like instead of being constrained by `tr`, which has inconsistent behavior. For instance :

```
gtr '\012' '高'   # UTF8 高 = \351\253\230 = xE9 xAB x98
```

on `bsd-tr`, `\n` will get replaced by the unicode properly `1高2高3高` , but if you're on `gnu-tr`, it would only keep the leading byte of the unicode, and result in

```
1 \351 2 \351 . . .
```

For unicode equiv-classes, bsd-tr works as expected while `gtr '[=高=]' '\v'` results in

```
gtr: ?\230: equivalence class operand must be a single character
```

and if u attempt equiv-classes with an arbitrary non-ASCII byte, bsd-tr does nothing while gnu-tr would gladly oblige, even if it means slicing straight through UTF8-compliant characters :

```
g3bn 77138 | (g)tr '[=\224=]' '\v'

bsd-tr : 77138=Koyote 코요태 KYT✜ 高耀太
gnu-tr : 77138=Koyote ?
                       ?
                         태 KYT✜ 高耀太
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do it following way, using GNU `AWK`, let `test.txt` content be

```
one
two
three
```

then

```
awk '{printf NR==1?"%s":"|%s", $0}' test.txt
```

output

```
one|two|three
```

Explanation: If it is first line print that line content sans trailing newline, otherwise `|` followed by line content sans trailing newline. Note that I assumed that `test.txt` has not trailing newline, if this is not case test this solution before applying it.

*(tested in gawk 5.0.1)*

Answer (score 0):

Also you can try this with `awk`:

```
awk '{ORS = (NR%3 ? "|" : RS)} 1' file
one|two|three
```

`%` is the modulo operator and `NR%3 ? "|" : RS` is a ternary expression.

- See Ed Morton's explanation here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55998710/14259465

Answer (score 0):

With a GNU `sed`, you can pass `-z` option to match line breaks, and thus all you need is replace each newline but the last one at the end of string:

```sh
sed -z 's/\n\(.\)/|\1/g' test.txt
perl -0pe 's/\n(?!\z)/|/g' test.txt
perl -pe 's/\n/|/g if !eof' test.txt
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/ELpHbc).

[image]

*Details*:

- `s` - substitution command
- `\n\(.\)` - an LF char followed with any one char captured into Group 1 (so `\n` at the end of string won't get matched)
- `|\1` - a `|` char and the captured char
- `g` - all occurrences.

The first *`perl`* command matches any LF char (`\n`) not at the end of string (`(?!\z)`) after slurping the whole file into a single string input (again, to make `\n` visible to the regex engine).

The second *`perl`* command replaces an LF  char at the end of each line except the one at the end of file (`eof`).

To make the changes inline add `-i` option (mind this is a GNU `sed` example):

```sh
sed -i -z 's/\n\(.\)/|\1/g' test.txt
perl -i -0pe 's/\n(?!\z)/|/g' test.txt
perl -i -pe 's/\n/|/g if !eof' test.txt
```

Comment: sed solution won't work for consecutive newlines (but probably not a valid input for OP). Perl retains the record separator by default, so you can use `perl -pe 's/\n/|/ if !eof'`

Comment: @Sundeep Thanks for a suggestion. And I only took into consideration the OP input. If there is a need to support consecutive newlines, I will change the suggested solutions or add alternatives.